# Java equivalent of loadHTMLFile that exists in PHP

Tags: java, php, spring, java-8

Is there an equivalent way of doing :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://myserver.com/test.html');
//Take some Ids of instance 
$element = $doc->getElementById('myId');
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Comment: Have a look at Jsoup : https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

Comment: Is there anything included by default in Java 8 ?

Comment: No, by default you can load an HTML page as text, but theree will be no parser (like JSoup)

Comment: There is no native java api for parsing HTML documents. You better to look into external libraries.